# How can a masonry dam not require mortar?

Tags: structural-engineering, masonry, hydroelectric-dams

[A Masonry Dam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masonry_dam) is build out of individual stones or bricks. The Wikipedia link says that it is "sometimes" joined with mortar, and has a cite for it but the link is 404 dead.

Is that really true? How could a masonry dam not require mortar? The dam needs to be water-tight against a wall of water, which has larger pressures at the bottom. I don't see how the individual blocks could be so tight and perfectly-fitting to stop water at high pressures.

I was unable to find a single example of a masonry dam that explicitly does not use mortar. I guess I'm missing something. Is there some other common seal mechanism besides mortar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "face" coating that provides the waterproof layer.

There are many materials used, from polymers to asphalt, cement etc

The material is chosen as it has to resit water movement - driven by wind etc

Comment: Thank you, i knew it had to be something simple.